# How to Draw Circles in Playground with Xcode

Tags: xcode

I'm working on a school project using Xcode and for part of it, I need to draw a circle on Xcode using Swift.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is decide how large of a circle you want – this will determine the parameters you set.  The first thing you do is make a constant named whatever you want and make it a square.  Then, you can use `variableName.layer.cornerRadius` to make your circle.  You have to use half of what you made the square as it is the radius of the circle.

Here's an example of a circle with a 10 radius:

```
let circle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 20, height: 20))

circle.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue //this is just so the circle is visible

circle.layer.cornerRadius = 10
```

> The really important thing to remember is that the square that you
>   originally make must have the width and height be twice the size of
>   the radius.  Also, if you are having trouble seeing the circle then it
>   might be because you didn't set a background color to it, so do
>   something like the code above by setting the color to anything you
>   want

.